# scss hover not working

Tags: css, sass, hover, frontend

I have some problems with hovering, it works in same code (css) fine, but not scss.
I set z-index on purpose in case that was the issue, but it isnt.

```
.arithmetics{
    height: 2.5em;
    width:  100%;
    text-align: center;

    div{
      width: 25%;
      font-size: 2em;
      line-height: 1.2em;
      display: inline-block;
      color: rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.79);
      vertical-align: top;
      background-color: rgba(218, 111, 111, 0.51);
      float: left;
      z-index: 10;

      &:hover{
        background-color: rgba(255, 179, 179, 0.51);
      }
    }
  }



  <div class="arithmetics">
    <div>+</div>
    <div>-</div>
    <div>/</div>
    <div>X</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Currently you are saying that div is a child of .arithmetics. Is that correct?

Comment: yes indeed, i want the hover to work on the divs

Comment: I always try debugging with giving the element I am searching for a red background. Try maybe to add that to the 'div' element to make sure it is in the right position to begin with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved this just now, apparently another div was overlaying the .arithmetics class. I changed the height of it and the buttons hover fine now.